# How get values variable javascript from razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

i have soure code :

```
$("#yes-modal").click(function (e) {
    var img = $("#url").val();
    window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadImages", "Hrd", new { id = *value variable img* })';
});
```

i want get value img, but i have error. 
How can do it ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax should work.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadImages", "Hrd", new { id = ' + img + '})';
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The razor syntax is a serverside code. It is evaluated while rendering the page from server. But the javascript is evaluated at the client side (browser). So you have to split it like below code.

```
$("#yes-modal").click(function (e) {
    var img = $("#url").val();
    var loc = '@Url.Action("DownloadImages", "Hrd")';
    var loc += '?id=' + img;
    window.location = loc;
});
```